# does usual ftp server need two threads for data connection and control conection?

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to write standard FTP server.
I wonder whether this scenario is correct or not?

```
1. On each request of clients, a thread manager makes thread for control connection.

2. When control connection thread receives PORT command, it establishes data connection(active open)
```

Is this usual solution? I wonder this since I have to create standard FTP server.

I would be happy if you answered JUST 'yes' or 'no'.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes. Or no. It depends on what FTP server you look at. Unix's `ftpd` and most of its variant fork processes, not threads.

Comment: but it still needs at least two, possibly three.

Comment: You said, "thread 1 is main thread, thread 2 is control connection, thread3 is data connection"??? totally 3?

Comment: A server usually supports more than one user, so you need a main thread to process incoming connections, it's the one with the listen in it.

Comment: main thread is used for listen. Is it good that another thread works for data and control connection? Totally 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, FTP uses two connections, read the RFC http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt, the wikipedia article is a bit friendlier http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol but the RFC is the bible.

As far as threads go you will need a thread to listen for incoming connections, a thread to process the control connection and a thread to process the data connection.  You could do it all with one thread by using asynchronous i/o using select.

Comment: I mistyped. My question is.. "Is it a usual solution to make one more thread for data connection??

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it, 3 threads, 1 thread, unix processes.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But I uses english as second language. I understand what you say partially. So you said there are 2 solutions. One is that main thread is listen thread. Then it is necessary that two thread work for data connection and control connection, respectively. Second is that I could use asynchronous i/o using select without threads. Right?